# Looping through dynamically generated tables with same ID using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have three tables dynamically generated from a database and all have the same id publicationtable.  Each table contains two sub tables with different classes shortcut and fullcut respectively.
I want to append the href that contains .pdf in each table to end the text contained within the td with class pubtitle and pubyear i.e

The jQuery I used is shown below, the problem is that the same title (enclosed with a td with class pubtitle) and year (enclosed withing td class pubyear) get repeated for the href in all the tables.  I want the hrefs in each table to get the title (title one, title two, title three) in each table

```
jQuery('#publicationtable').each(function() {
var title = jQuery(.pubtitle).text();
var link = jQuery('.shortcut a[href*=".pdf"]')
jQuery(link).attr('href', function() {
return jQuery(link).href + jQuery('.pubtitle' ).first().text().trim() + ","  + jQuery('.pubyear' ).first().text().trim();
});
});
```

Markup for the dynamically generated tables

```
<table id="publicationtable" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td align="left" width="115" valign="top" rowspan="6">
    <table class="shortcut" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">                        
    <tbody><tr>
    <td width="28%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="listChecked" value="^m1730^h1">
    </td>   
    <td width="72%">
    <font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b>select</b></i></font>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td width="28%">
    &nbsp;</td> 
    <td width="72%">
    <b>
    <font face="verdana" size="1"><i>to print</i></font></b>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100%" class="publang"><font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b>
    <a href="test.pdf">English</a>[1.89Mb]</b></i></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100%" class="publang"><font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b>
    <a href="test1.pdf">French</a>[1.92Mb]</b></i></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100%" class="publang"><font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b>
    <a href="test3.pdf">Arabic</a>[1.9Mb]</b></i></font></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </td>
    <td width="485">
    </td></tr><tr><td><b><font color="#000000" size="2" face="Verdana">
    1730</font></b></td></tr><tr><td class="pubtitle"><b>
    <font face="Verdana" size="2">Title one</font></b></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class="pubyear">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>
    <font color="#000000" size="2" face="Verdana">&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr><td><font color="#000000" size="2" face="Verdana">
    </font></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></center>

    <center>

    <b><font color="#FF0000" size="5">This is the second table </font></b>
    <table id="publicationtable" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr>
    <td align="left" width="115" valign="top" rowspan="6">
    <table class="shortcut" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">                        
    <tbody><tr>
    <td width="28%">
    <input type="checkbox" name="listChecked" value="">
    </td>   
    <td width="72%">
    <font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b>select</b></i></font>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td width="28%">
    &nbsp;</td> 
    <td width="72%">
    <b>
    <font face="verdana" size="1"><i>to print</i></font></b>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100%"><font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b><a href="book1.pdf">English</a>[1.89Mb]</b></i></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100%"><font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b><a href="book2.pdf">French</a>[1.92Mb]</b></i></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="100%"><font face="verdana" size="1"><i><b><a href="book3.pdf">Arabic[</a>1.9Mb]</b></i></font></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </td>
    <td width="485">
    </td></tr><tr><td><b><font color="#000000" size="2" face="Verdana">
    1729</font></b></td></tr><tr><td class="pubtitle"><b>
    <font face="Verdana" size="2">Title two</font></b></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class="pubyear">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>
    &nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td><font color="#000000" size="2" face="Verdana">
    </font></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></center>
    <!-- End of table two -->
```

Comment: _"have three tables dynamically generated from a database and all have the same id publicationtable"_ Note, `html` element `id` attribute should be unique

Comment: ID attribute of any HTML element must be unique as it is with a variable in any programming language. You can use classes instead.